# Adding http request header to href link with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am scraping external website and using cfx_http5 tag to get data as `cfhttp` is very slow, so with `cfx_http5`, it does not do the resolveurl, with cfhttp it do the resolveurl so make the url point to same domain from where file is coming

now i need to use the cfx tag, but all my url's coming as:

with cfx_http5

```
<a href="details.cfm?acb=1>cick</a>
```

with cfhttp:

```
<a href="http://theddomain.com/details.cfm?acb=1>cick</a>
```

so how can i add a code in coldfusion to append this url to all the href tags

please guide

Comment: Not sure, if you get a chance to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183903/cfhttp-first-request-fast-following-slow

Comment: Check out jSoup - http://jsoup.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`<cfset httpResult = ReplaceNoCase(httpResult, '<a href="', '<a href="http://theddomain.com/', 'all')>`

Comment: I ran this code on my server and it worked:
<cfset httpResult = '<a href="details.cfm?acb=1">click</a> <a href="details2.cfm?acb=2">click 2</a>'>
<cfset httpResult = ReplaceNoCase(httpResult, '<a href="', '<a href="http://theddomain.com/', 'all')>
<cfdump var="#httpResult#">
The result was this:
<a href="http://theddomain.com/details.cfm?acb=1">click</a> <a href="http://theddomain.com/details2.cfm?acb=2">click 2</a>

Comment: @cfsam: if you post more of your code (like the cfx_http5 part, and what you're doing with the result), we could help you more.